# Roots of polynomial of order 12

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to find the roots of a polynomial P by entering

```
solx = solve(P)
```

where

```
P = p(p(p(p(x)))
```

with `p(x) = r*x*(1-x)`

However, all my roots are being returned as

```
RootOf(Q)
```

where Q is P as a complex polynomial.

How do I return the exact symbolic solutions that I need to complete my analysis (I need to find the derivatives of these roots)?

Complete code:

```
syms r x;
p = symfun(r*x*(1-x),x);
P = p(p(p(p(x))));
[Q,R] = quorem(P-x, p(p(x))-x)
solve(Q)
```

Comment: Please post a complete code snippet that reproduces the problem. How do you define `P`? Do you want symbolic or numeric result? Adding tags to the question also helps

Comment: @LuisMendo I have edited my question!

Comment: What is `r´? Please initialize all variables in your example code.

Comment: @Daniel I am trying to find r, I want to find r when the derivative of the root equals -1

Comment: Please put the complete code you are running into your question. At some point I understand your description wrong. I end up with a higher degree polynomial but it can be solved.

Comment: @Daniel I've put in the complete code in my question

Comment: wouldn't that be a polynomial of order 16?

Comment: And if I recall correctly, there is no general symbolic solution for polynomials of more than order 4 (see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/786/120 ) so you may be stuck. You're talking about the **logistic map** (http://www.emba.uvm.edu/~jxyang/teaching/Math266new/notes_6_1.htm) and you may have to resort to numeric rather than symbolic methods. Suggest asking on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: also, solving P==0 is different than solving P==x.

Answer (score 1):

There is [no algebraic solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) for arbitrary polynomials with degree 5 or higher. Matlab can not solve it unless you substitue `r` with a known value. To solve it for a known `r` use:

```
solve(subs(Q,'r',sym(1)))
```

When originally trying to understand your question I tried `solve(P)` which is one of the examples of a higher degree polynomial which can be solved, because it is already factorized.